# Product additionnal buttons in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce, how do I add a "Continue" button inked to the the product page just after?

And inside the product page how to add a checkout button just under the add to cart button?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will:

- **In woocommerce archive pages:** Add an additional button "Continue" linked to the product *(for simple products)*
- **In single product pages:** Add an additional button linked to checkout page.

The code:

```
// Archives pages: Additional button linked to the product
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_continue_button', 15 );
function loop_continue_button(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        $link = $product->get_permalink();
        $text = __("Continue", "woocommerce");

        echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button alt" style="margin-top:10px;">' . $text . '</a>';
    }
}

// Single product pages: Additional button linked to checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_additional_checkout_button', 1 );
function product_additional_checkout_button() {
    global $product;

    // For variable product types
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_checkout_button', 21 );
    }
    // For all other product types
    else {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_checkout_button', 31 );
    }
}

function custom_checkout_button() {
    $link = wc_get_checkout_url();
    $text = __("Proceed to checkout", "woocommerce");
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button alt" style="margin-bottom:14px;">' . $text . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 's this the link to my developing site check how it displayed http://box5202.temp.domains/~iboconne/

Comment: @Lexissmigz because you need to add the necessary CSS rules to get the right display.

Comment: Could you be of help ??

Comment: @Lexissmigz I don't do any theming or styling sorry... just pure coding.

Comment: is there a way i can contact you through your mail?